# Converting a string list with null and text to integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a string list with null values and numbers entered as strings ['1', '2', '',...) into an integer list where the null values are zeros [1, 2, 0,...]. The code I am using right now gets rid of my lists and returns a single 0:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmhpu.jpg)

```
try:
    input1 = int('column1')
except ValueError:
    input1 = 0
try:
    input2 = int('column2')
except ValueError:
    input2 = 0
try:
    input3 = int('column3')
except ValueError:
    input3 = 0

print(input1)
0
```

Comment: No No. You were right before. Please remove the image. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension to convert each value to `int`, or if its an empty string just use `0`.

```
>>> values = ['1', '2', '', '4']
>>> [int(i) if i else 0 for i in values]
[1, 2, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
some_data = ['1', '2', '', '3', '', '4']
new_data = []

for i in some_data :
    if i != '':
        new_data.append(int(i))
    else:
        new_data.append(0)

print(some_data)
print(new_data)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3 helping.py 
> ['1', '2', '', '3', '', '4']
> [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]
> ```

Seems the task could be simpler using a for loop.  First set a `for` loop to cycle through the items in `some_data`.  Then for each item check `if i != '':`. If the item passes, we can `append` the item as an `int`, `else` in the case of the item being `''` we can `append` a `0`.